# Day trading minimum capital

Tags: trading

If there is a minimum capital necessary needed to day trade, can't I just use a normal account and day trade with that if I don't use margin?

Comment: Because? I mean, you ask about reason? It is a regulation made by people in charge. Is this the first time in your life you encounter stupid rules?

Answer (score 3):

In the US, FINRA rules define a Pattern Day Trader as any customer who makes more than three day trades within a rolling five business day period, provided that the number of day trades represents more than six percent of the customer’s total trades in the margin account for that same five business day period.

Customers who are deemed Pattern Day Traders can only trade in margin accounts and must have at least $25k in their account  on any day that trades are made and it must be in the account prior to the day trading. If the account drops below $25k, no day trades will be allowed until the account is restored to the $25k minimum equity level.

If the day trading buying power limitation is exceeded you will be issued a day-trading margin call. You will have at most, 5 business days to deposit funds to meet the call. Until the call is met, day-trading will be restricted to two times maintenance margin excess. If the margin call is not met by the fifth business day, the account will be further restricted to trading only on a cash available basis for 90 days or until the call is met.

A  PDT can trade four times the maintenance margin excess in the account as of the close of business of the previous day (2:1 allowed overnight).  Brokers have the right to set more restrictive levels.

You can day trade in a Cash Account as long as the activity does not result in free riding, which is the sale of securities bought with unsettled funds.  IOW, as long as you have settled funds,  the PDT rules and the minimum  equity requirement of $25k do not apply.

Comment: I have to use a margin account to day trade? What if I use my regular cash account?

Comment: See the last paragraph.

Comment: @BobBaerker you may wish to explain the settlement process and why as soon as you sell an instrument you don't immediately have the settled cash to trade with.

Comment: Wouldn't that be called unsettled funds?  (see last paragraph)

Comment: In the 2nd paragraph you said "can only trade in margin accounts" but the last paragraph says I can trade in cash accounts. So can I day trade in cash accounts?

Comment: You may trade settled funds.